# Crystal report record move to the next page but his place is empty

Tags: crystal-reports

Crystal report record move to the next page but his place is empty
I have a box-like table the problem is when the textobject grow here palce in the table get empty and he moves to the next page like this

[image: First page]
[image: Second page]

Comment: Please share a code you have used to deal with the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm understanding that you want one of your objects splitted along the two pages, but it is being moved to the second page.

If that's the point, then the solution is to right click your object (maybe it is a text box) and ***uncheck* the option "keep object together"**.

This is something boring to work. Maybe you will need to change this option in the section too. Try it out.